# Regex, single match - Recursion vs. Subroutine Call

Tags: regex, recursion, subroutine

A common real-world use is to match a balanced set of parentheses.

`\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)` matches a single pair of parentheses with any text in between, including an unlimited number of parentheses, as long as they are all properly paired. (...)

If you want a regex that does not find any matches in a string that contains unbalanced parentheses, then you need to use a subroutine call instead of recursion. (AND THIS IS WHAT I DONT UNDERSTAND ->). If you want to find a sequence of multiple pairs of balanced parentheses as a single match, then you also need a subroutine call.

So using "(?R)" will not produce a "single match". Is it something different than a "single match", something like multiple matches in one match?

Source: 
https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html

"Matching balanced constructs" part.

Comment: Just read the tutorial, follow all the links there. `(?R)` is also a subroutine call to Group 0 (the whole pattern).

Comment: Yes, but what I get with the (?R) is NOT a single match? Something other than "single". How / in what way?

Comment: Recursion has nothing to do with single/multiple matches. Have you got a real case to consider?

Comment: Yes, the one in the above example can be used. I will be reading about the subroutines, like you said. I thought I read it already, but I have not gotten to this yet (it is the next page of this). In general - "(?R)" comes back to the beginning of the regex (starts from the beginning) and if it matches it creates the "recursion depths". But it comes back to the beginning, right? Thanks!

Comment: The regex engine just reapplies the same regex on each level of recursion, whatever it may be. If it help you to think it terms of "comes back at the beginning" you can do that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you want to find a sequence of multiple pairs of balanced
>   parentheses as a single match, then you also need a subroutine call.

I believe what this is saying that if you want to match this `(.)(.)` - a sequence of multiple pairs of balanced parentheses - then you need to use subroutines. I admit, an example would have helped in the tutorial.

Why will recursion fail to return "as a single match"? This simply because of the way recursion works - it is applying the same regex to an ever decreasing string (if it's not infinitely recursing) and returning a result when it reaches a non-matching element, then proceeding further along the string. It does not match `(.)(.)` as a single string, because it is not defined to do so (you can do that using quantifiers: `(?>\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)){2}` or more generally: `(?>\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\))*`).

Here is what the pattern presented in the tutorial produces for `a sequence of multiple pairs of balanced parentheses` (line 1) and `for balanced constructs or nested constructs` (line 2):

[image]

Comment: The [`(?>\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/g14u8J/1) pattern will not match balanced parentheses. You need to define a capturing group to exclude the limiting quantifier and recurse it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question about regular expression and recursion. But if your original task is to find **matches/not matches** between parentheses, what about not use regular expression for this simple task. Probably it is easier to write a coupe of lines to solve this problem:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> findAllPairs(String str) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    Deque<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    char[] symbols = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        if (symbols[i] == '(')
            stack.push(i);
        else if (symbols[i] == ')') {
            if (stack.isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not pair ')' at position " + i);
            map.put(stack.pop(), i);
        }
    }

    if (!stack.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Total " + stack.size() + " not pair '('");

    return map;
}
```